# SQL statement works in PGAdmin, but not in app after transposing to Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I wrote this sql statement in PGAdmin and it pulls the data as expected.

```
SELECT Sum(timerecords.manual_input_hours)           AS hours,
       To_date(timerecords.time_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date,
       tasks.title,
       timerecords.client_id
FROM   timerecords
       INNER JOIN tasks
               ON tasks.id = timerecords.task_id
WHERE  timerecords.client_id = '15'
GROUP  BY To_date(timerecords.time_start, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
          timerecords.task_id,
          timerecords.client_id,
          tasks.title
ORDER  BY date DESC
```

I then ran the sql statement in scuttle.io to transform to Arel

```
Timerecord.select(
  [
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
      'SUM', [Timerecord.arel_table[:manual_input_hours]]
    ).as('hours'), Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
      'TO_DATE', [Timerecord.arel_table[:time_start], 'YYYY-MM-DD']
    ).as('date'), Task.arel_table[:title], Timerecord.arel_table[:client_id]
  ]
).where(Timerecord.arel_table[:client_id].eq('15')).joins(
  Timerecord.arel_table.join(Task.arel_table).on(
    Task.arel_table[:id].eq(Timerecord.arel_table[:task_id])
  ).join_sources
).order(:date).reverse_order.group(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
    'TO_DATE', [Timerecord.arel_table[:time_start], 'YYYY-MM-DD']
  ), Timerecord.arel_table[:task_id], Timerecord.arel_table[:client_id], Task.arel_table[:title]
)
```

I am getting this as an error when I call @tasks.each.do (at that line), but no additional info.

```
Arel::Visitors::UnsupportedVisitError in Agency::Clientmanagement#show
Unsupported argument type: String. Construct an Arel node instead.
```

A couple of items I tried from researching.. instead of to_date, i tried to_char. I also changed my development db from sqllite3 to postgresql to match production server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated code is extremely overcomplicated as it uses Arel for stuff thats easy to do with the ActiveRecord query interface:

```
tbl = Timerecord.arel_table
date_fn = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
  'TO_DATE', [tbl[:time_start], Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('YYYY-MM-DD')]
)

Timerecord.select(
  tbl[:manual_input_hours].sum.as('hours'), # you don't need to define the function
  date_fn.as('date'), 
  Task.arel_table[:title].as('title')
  :client_id
)  
  .where(client_id: '15')
  .joins(:tasks)
  .order(date: :desc)
  .group(
     :date, :task_id, :client_id, :title
  )
```

Comment: I haven't heard of scuttle.io and while its a fun concept the code it generates is a maintainence nightmare.

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks, edited it to point to the correct table.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `Arel::Nodes.build_quoted` to cast your date format.

try

```rb
Timerecord.select(
  [
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
      'SUM', [Timerecord.arel_table[:manual_input_hours]]
    ).as('hours'), 
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('TO_DATE',
     [Timerecord.arel_table[:time_start], Arel::Nodes.build_quoted('YYYY-MM-DD')]
    ).as('date'), 
    Task.arel_table[:title], 
    Timerecord.arel_table[:client_id]
  ]
).where(Timerecord.arel_table[:client_id].eq('15')).joins(
  Timerecord.arel_table.join(Task.arel_table).on(
    Task.arel_table[:id].eq(Timerecord.arel_table[:task_id])
  ).join_sources
).order(:date).reverse_order.group(
 :date, 
 Timerecord.arel_table[:task_id], 
 Timerecord.arel_table[:client_id], 
 Task.arel_table[:title]
)
```